# Limiting foreach information

Tags: php, limit

I have a foreach that creates a url for each item based on the `$mainCat` and `$subCat` of course I know that there will be duplicates due to some items being in the same categories.

Is there away that I can just return one url of each `$mainCat` & `$subCat` properties?

```
    foreach ($detailsFunction as $main) 
    {
        $ld = array('listingId' => $main['listingId']);

        foreach($ld as $id)
        {
            $mainlisting = $main['listingId'];
            $mainCat     = strtolower($main['mainCat']);
            $subCatO     = strtolower($main['subCat']);
            $subCat      = str_replace(" ", "-", $subCatO);

            $structure = base_url().'listings/'.$mainCat.'/'.$subCat;

            $url[] = $structure;
        }

    }
        return $url;

        var_dump($url);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question you want to produce an array without duplicate values?

You could test if the `$structure` is in `$url` before you add it:

```
if (!in_array($structure, $url)) $url[] = $structure;
```

or use `array_unique` after your loops are done:

```
$url = array_unique($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use PHP array_unique to remove duplicates

More information on [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)